# porque mi parametro cambia radicalmente su valor solo en js

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo un problema que no entiendo y le hice el seguimiento de la variable para saber donde cambia.

Tengo un input con una funcion onclick donde paso un id. Este id son 4 numeros, puede ser 0123 o 1234. Cuando entra a la función del onclick, este id (enviado como parametro) cambia su valor de forma muy radical por ejemplo:

```
example(0746)
function example(id){
 console.log(id)--> imprime 486
}
```

Hice otras pruebas en un playground de js y a lo sumo deberia cambiarlo a 746 sin el 0 inicial siendo numerico. Intente pasarlo como string al valor e igualmente se imprime mal los ids. Pero en el siguiente caso la funcion no cambia el id:

```
example(1746)
function example(id){
 console.log(id)--> imprime 1746
}
```

La verdad que no entiendo porque tiene ese comportamiento.

Answer (score 2):

En javascript los números que comienzan por 0 se consideran en base octal (base 8), por lo tanto, 0746 es 746 en octal, que en decimal sería el 486

Comment: Hola Pedro, gracias por tu repuesta, me parecia que el problema iba por ese lado. Lo resolvi con id.toString(8) donde 8 representa la base para volverlo a octal. Lo que no me quedo muy claro es el porque lo convierte si lo paso como string, entiendo que en js distingue los numeros por mas que sea str, pero ¿no respeta el tipo de dato original de la variable?

Comment: Esto es así por convenio, los números que empiezan por 0x son hexadecimales, los que empiezan por 0 son octales y el resto los considera decimales. Supongo que es por hacerlo igual que en C, en el que también se sigue este convenio. Nunca me ha gustado ya que se presta mucho a errores de este tipo, pienso que podían haber elegido para los octales algo como 8x o algo similar. Pero el caso es que lo han  hecho así y hay que acostumbrarse :D.

Comment: No te puedo decir por qué lo convierte porque no has incluido el resto del código, desde que se recoge el input hasta que se llama a la función **example**, en algún punto habrás hecho algo que lo convierte a número